# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Coredata>' to <Coredata>'

Tags: c#

I'm getting this error message "Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.List<Coredata>` to `<Coredata>`"

while compiling my project
Can somebody help me?

```
var Data1  = new List<Coredata>();

Data1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Coredata>>(responseFromServer); 

// Convert json data to .net object

return Data1;
```

Comment: What's the function signature? You are missing the part that actually throws here. And what is the _actual_ error message?

Comment: We also need to see the contents of `responseFromServer`

Comment: @MattBurland: Here is the error message: Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List<Coredata> to <Coredata>

Comment: Could it be that your function is expected to return a value of type `Coredata`, whereas you are here returning `Data1` which is of type `List<Coredata>`?

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the responseFromServer value? Seems like you are trying to parse a different structure.

> The name 'data' does not exist in the current context

From where is comming this 'data' name?

Comment: Its sorry, i've changed the above code to like this :     var data1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Coredata>>(responseFromServer);

Comment: Please, post the JSON string. 
you json must be something like this:
[{
  "id": null,
  "number": null,
  "createdDate": null,
  "lastUpdateDate": null,
  "type": null,
  "state": null,
  "shortDescription": null,
  "application": null,
  "assignee": null
},
{
  "id": null,
  "number": null,
  "createdDate": null,
  "lastUpdateDate": null,
  "type": null,
  "state": null,
  "shortDescription": null,
  "application": null,
  "assignee": null
}]

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code to just this:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Coredata>>(responseFromServer);
```

Comment: I'm changed it, but now i'm getting the error message "The name 'data' does not exist in the current context';

Comment: public class Coredata
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string number { get; set; }
        public string createdDate { get; set; }
        public string lastUpdateDate { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public string shortDescription { get; set; }
        public string application { get; set; }
        public string assignee { get; set; }
    }

Comment: When i've changed the code to var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Coredata>>(responseFromServer);

Comment: I'm getting this error message now: "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'EchoBotnivin.domain.Coredata' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Comment: It sounds like the data in "responseFromServer" is not JSON data

Comment: The data from responsefromserver, is a JSON one, i've just passed it with the JSON validator

Comment: Can someone help me on this?

Comment: You need to include more information, such as your full code sample and the data.  Otherwise it's impossible for people to help solve the problem.